# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: referenced from subhook-9679a6.o

Tags: c++, c, linker, hook, dylib

Error:

```
"subhook_unprotect(void*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _subhook_new in subhook-9679a6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Linking command: `g++ -dynamiclib -fPIC -v -o finalcalling.dylib finalversion.cpp /Users/~/Desktop/c/subhook-master/subhook.c -std=c++11`

After going through my code I found that `subhook_unprotect(void*, unsigned long)` is not even in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your code https://github.com/Zeex/subhook then it seems you are supposed to also include subhook_unix.c in your build. That file does define `subhook_unprotect`. So does subhook_windows.c but I'm assuming you are on a unix like platform.

Comment: Thank you! I was using that code on macos, that error dissapeared now, I just need to get passed a bunch of redefinition errors that have popped up now though.

Comment: When I said *include* I meant include in your build not `#include` in your source file.

Comment: Wait a minute, I'm getting redefinition errors from the same lines???
```In file included from finalversion.cpp:10:
./subhook_x86.c:522:33: error: redefinition of 'subhook_free'
SUBHOOK_EXPORT void SUBHOOK_API subhook_free(subhook_t hook) {
                                ^
./subhook_x86.c:522:33: note: previous definition is here
SUBHOOK_EXPORT void SUBHOOK_API subhook_free(subhook_t hook) {
```

Comment: Never `#include` a .c or a .cpp file.

Comment: am I missing something, I included it in the main.cpp file, but used your advice and removed it, and to work around that I included it in the main ```g++ -dynamiclib -fPIC -v -o finalcalling.dylib finalversion.cpp /Users/~/Desktop/c/subhook-master/subhook.c /Users/~/Desktop/c/subhook-master/subhook_unix.c -std=c++11``` but that just got me back to the same error ```"subhook_unprotect(void*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _subhook_new in subhook-ea1cf5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64```

Comment: @BigBored So I no nothing about this package, I'm just googling. But according to documentation you are only supposed to compile subhook.c so your original build was correct. But if you look at the end of subhook.c it seems you are supposed to define `SUBHOOK_UNIX` as part of the build. This doesn't seem to be mentioned in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: @BigBored Or you are supposed to include subhook_unix.c in the build and instead are supposed to define `SUBHOOK_SEPARATE_SOURCE_FILES`. Seems a little bit unnecessarily complicated if you ask me

Comment: I attempted defining subhook_unix and subhook_x86  but no matter what I do, I just get the same error again: ```"subhook_unprotect(void*, unsigned long)", referenced from:       _subhook_new in subhook-ea1cf5.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64``` Q: Where do I define it? Main.cpp or subhook.c? Q:How do I define it? is ```#define SUBHOOK_SEPARATE_SOURCE_FILES SUBHOOK_UNIX, SUBHOOK_X86_64``` correct?

Comment: @BigBored I would define it when you build using the `-D` option, so its defined throughout your code, something like `g++ -DSUBHOOK_UNIX -dynamiclib -fPIC -v -o finalcalling.dylib finalversion.cpp /Users/~/Desktop/c/subhook-master/subhook.c -std=c++11`

Comment: I'm not sure why this is still occurring anymore, I even used -DSUBHOOK_X86 to make sure I was including all the paths I needed, but the error still persists.

Comment: @BigBored I downloaded the library. I was completely unable to compile the source with g++, it's not legal C++. However I had no trouble with gcc. `gcc -I. main.c subhook.c` worked fine for me.